# asp.net identity cookie became very large

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I have been using a asp.net identity to provide a federal authentication system for my tow of ASP.NET MVC 5 applications with SSO. User authorization is based on claims to access business modules and user controls in the application.

But now I am thinking about an issue. Cause there are many business modules in those apps, so there are many claims and which is making the cookie very long. For example, my cookie is around 3888 bytes long and for chrome it is 4096 bytes per cookie. I was wandering if my cookie size exceeds that limit will there be a problem? And how do I solve it?

Comment: Instead of mentioning every separate object that a user has access to, group them together and give a user access to the groups containing them? We can't really say anything else if you don't show the implementation.

Comment: Another option would be to resolve the claims at the server side from the auth ticket id. And store only minimal data in the actual cookie.

Comment: @CodeCaster I understand the point. I have them grouped but Unfortunately it is still big.

Comment: YES - It will cause problems, and you need to do something about it, reduce data you store or compress your cookie contents.

Comment: @DaiBok is there any way to store it to server side

Comment: it depends how your system is set up. If you behind a load balancer, can cause problems. You could store Auth data in your BD and retrieve bits when you need them. A bit of a overhead, but better that customers complaining they can not log in